# Há previsão para quando o site vai estabilizar depois da migração de Data Center?

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Alguns não sabem mas sábado houve uma mudança de data center da StackExchange. Alguns devem ter notado problemas de acesso ao *site*. Eu ainda estou tendo problemas em vários momentos. Está bem chato ter que ficar esperando para acessar o que se deseja. Aparentemente está afetando mais o SOpt que o SO. Parece estar mais estável, mas em vários momentos enrosca e requisição AJAX, aparece a página da CloudFlare e atrapalha o fluxo. Acho que não é um problema só comigo.

Vocês sabe de algo?

- [Twitter](https://twitter.com/stackstatus)
- [Blog](http://stackstatus.net/)

Continua ruim e está atrapalhando bastante o uso normal do site. Agora tem usuários em desvantagem em relação aos que não sofrem o problema.

## Atualizações

10 dias e a situação está pior que antes.

Nova atualização completando 2 semanas de problemas:

O SOpt está sem problemas mas os outros sites continuam inacessíveis em vários momentos. Se eu fosse fornecedor de infraestrutura e ficasse 2 semanas dando problemas, já teria perdido o cliente.

Em 09/09/2015 12:46 o SOpt teve problemas. O meta não (estou escrevendo agora), o SOen não. Tem outros sites de terceiros tendo o mesmo problema com a CloudFlare no mesmo momento. Durou alguns minutos.

Em 29/09 voltamos ter problemas.

## 2016

Em 05/01/2016 comecei ter problemas de novo. O problema é CloudFlare, porque o chat nunca dá problema. Outros sites que eu sei que usam o CF estão no mesmo "gás". Os que não usam, estão 100%. O problema tem dado só em horário comercial. Eu acho que é regional.

Comment: Não tive problema nenhum hoje, mas não usei o site no fim de semana.

Comment: Hoje está melhor, mas já tive algo entre 10 e 20 atrasos grandes ou erros.

Comment: Final de semana estava complicado mesmo.

Comment: Não notei nada de anormal, nem durante o fim de semana.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263697/176034

Comment: Estou tendo problemas por vários momentos aqui também.

Comment: Hoje tá complicado aqui, :(

Comment: Já pensou em postar isso no MSE? Tem hora que está impossível acessar outros sites da rede.

Comment: Have you seen this problem since [Fri Sep 4 14:47:47 UTC 2015](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2015&month=9&day=4&hour=14&min=0&sec=0&p1=45&p2=179&p3=133)?

Comment: @TomOnTime No problems on SOpt since 2015-08-18. I can't speak about SO and network, it's too soon.

Comment: @TomOnTime see the edit.

Comment: @JorgeB. A instabilidade de hoje é na rede toda, não específica do SOpt: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/648851999820087296

Comment: @Gabe já tinha visto, o JNat mandou-me o link no PL.

Comment: Este problema nunca mais acaba...

Answer (score 7):

Eu tive problema ontem e hoje novamente ao meio dia. Além do SOpt, também ocorreu no UX:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Agora praticamente acabou aqui pra mim. Quando vai fazer algumas coisas em AJAX, obviamente não aparece isto mas está tendo o mesmo problema.

Comment: Hoje a tarde já não vi mais, mas só aparece quando eu mais preciso kk

Comment: Isto é fato :D :D

Answer (score 4):

Desde o sábado a gente não teve mais nenhum problema. A própria mudança, alias, ocorreu mais sem problemas do que eu esperava, levando em consideração as migrações anteriores.

O CloudFlare pode ter enlouquecido brevemente, como já aconteceu no passado, mas hoje tudo já deve estar estabilizado. Eu não tive problema algum ainda, nem de falha nem de lentidão.

Se você tiver com problemas de maneira consistente, tente conseguir o log do que está acontecendo.

## UPDATE

A gente entrou em contato com o CloudFlare pra saber qual o problema com o servidor deles em São Paulo. Mais detalhes assim que eles responderem.

## UPDATE 2

Ainda sem resposta concreta do CloudFlare. Eles estão investigando, mas não temos nenhum resultado.

## UPDATE 3

A conversa com a Cloud Flare continua, sem muito avanço.
Nesse meio tempo, desabilitamos o Cloud Flare para o SOpt. Deve demorar algum tempo pra propagar, mas os problemas provavelmente devem parar hoje.

#### UPDATE 3.1

A essa altura a alteração desabilitando o Cloud Flare já propagou há tempo. Me avisem se continuarem tendo problemas.

## UPDATE 4

A instabilidade de hoje não é específica do SOpt, ou usuários no Brasil:
[image: Twitter ao resgate]

Comment: Durante a madrugada de segunda aproximadamente as "3:00 UTC" o SOen entrou em readonly e o SOpt ficou por algum tempo e algumas vezes fora do ar, apresentando erro 502 ou 503 de HTTP (não me lembro). Acredito que o SOpt não tenha versão readonly e por isto não tenha apresentado tal página e apresentava o erro, me pareceu alguma manutenção, pois então não teria a tela de readonly no SOen, a não ser que tal tela seja automatica.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não tenho certeza se temos read-only. Eu *acho* que sim. Mas a diferença entre o comportamento do SOen e SOpt é que eles ficam em servidores diferentes (mas no mesmo data center). Por questões de demanda, o SOen tem um servidor só pra ele, enquanto todos os outros sites dividem um outro servidor). O roteamento dos servidores também é diferente, então nem sempre o SOen vai se comportar igual ao resto da rede.

Comment: Entendi, talvez isto explique o motivo de não ter visto a página de read-only no SOpt.

Comment: Eu vi o R/O no sábado. O SO parece estar bem mais estável e não vi problema nem domingo, nem hoje, Mas o SOpt está toda hora dando problemas. Sempre volta rápido. Parece estar melhorando ao longo do dia.

Comment: @bigown Vi o pessoal conversando agora sobre um problema no SOru, e pelo visto nem todos os caches foram expirados/renovados ainda, o que pode estar causando alguns problemas...

Comment: Novo "queda" a 4 minutos atrás (1:35 UTC) - http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGsg9.png

Comment: Estou tendo o mesmo problema neste exato momento.

Comment: Tinha melhorado, mas parece que piorou agora. Incluindo o SO.

Comment: Não será problema ai no Brasil? Aqui não se passa nada, também temos a melhor rede de fibra do mundo não é ;)

Comment: Mais um 502 agora

Comment: Hoje está tão ruim quanto domingo. Eu já tinha percebido por outros sites que essa Cloud Flare, pelo menos aqui no Brasil causa mais problemas do que ajuda.

Comment: @bigown Até agora não temos resposta da CloudFlare... mas parece bem claro que o problema é do lado deles, e acho que só no sudeste (mas não tenho certeza)

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim. O problema parece estar restrito a uma região do Brasil apenas

Comment: Imagino que não tenha nenhum jeito de contornar isso até que o problema se resolva, certo? Hoje quando a coisa estava muito ruim eu usei um proxy para consultar os sites da SE, mas como meu login é via Google (eu não tenho senha na SE, e mesmo se tivesse não animaria entrar com ela num proxy) eu passei a maior parte do tempo podendo ler mas não escrever.

Comment: @mgibsonbr quem está sofrendo com isto está em desvantagem em relação aos outros usuários, e já vai fazer uma semana que está assim.

Comment: Estou odiando o 502 tanto quanto o 404.

Comment: Algum novidade @Gabe :?  No sábado tava acontecendo com mais frequência do que durante a semana.

Comment: @emanuelsn Nada... sinto muito

Answer (score 3):

Agora também deste lado do atlântico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Gabe problemas deste lado também.

Comment: Hoje também vi uns 521 no SOen e no SOpt.

Comment: Neste momento fiz *refresh* na página das [perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) e só apareceram 3! Além que a página não foi completamente lida, as partes laterais não apareceram.